# except ValueError not tripping Python 3.4

Tags: python, exception, python-3.4

Alright so I'm trying to basically prevent someone from typing a string value into the field:

```
#User selection
print("Which program would you like to run?")
print("(Type '9' if you wish to exit the menu)")
selection = int(input())
print()

#Security statement followed by case statement
while selection <= 0 or selection >= 10:
    try:
        print("That is an invalid selection, please input a proper selection.")
        print("Which program would you like to run?")
        selection = int(input())
        print()
    except ValueError:
        print("Cmon man")
```

Plain and simple, it's not running. I've tried reorganizing everything and I haven't found a proper solution. Been looking around for almost an hour now. No help to the issue. Any kind souls?

Ignore the case statement portion btw, that's not even written yet.

P.S. Just keep getting usual "String isn't a number durr" response

("ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'why'")

P.P.S. Issue is already pointed out. I'm apparently stupidly oblivious lol... Thanks for the help.

Comment: You realize your try-except block for validating the selection is only around the second `input` statement, don't you? That is: if you answer a non-number to the first input, the program will break there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `try...except` doesn't cover the initial user input and so the `ValueError` isn't actually caught.
If you enter an `int` outside the bounds defined (0 >= x >= 10) as the first input then you can see the `try...except` blocks working.

You'll need to refactor your code so that the first input request is inside your try block and the loop or wrap the existing input request in another `try...except`.

Also, as a side note, `input()` can take a string argument that will be displayed as a prompt to the user.

```
selection = int(input("Which program would you like to run? "))
```

Comment: Any suggestion by chance as to how best implement the try...except form in the beginning? I'd like to keep the while as is. I've been trying to mess with a try...except in the first request for input but it seems to be much more of a mess than I anticipated.

Comment: I would probably refactor everything into the one while loop (`while True:`) and break out on valid input. If invalid input print the error and loop back to the start again. If you're not sure how to go about that I can edit in an example into my answer.

Comment: Nah I gotchu. I can rewrite it, I just was really hoping not to. Too late to be dealing with stuff like this lol.

Comment: Sunday night cram for a Monday morning deadline??  =0p  I remember those all too well. Good luck with it!